# Deleting rows have most of the value zero

Tags: r

File-

```
    i   j   k   l   m   n
a   0   0   0   1   0   1
b   8   6   34  1   0   0
c   0   9   12  0   8   0
d   7   9   3   7   0   5
e   0   0   0   1   0   0
f   2   3   9   6   8   9
g   0   1   0   3   1   5
h   0   9   0   8   4   0
```

I want to delete those rows which vane value 0 in more than 3 cells.

Expected output-

```
    i   j   k   l   m   n
b   8   6   34  1   0   0
d   7   9   3   7   0   5
f   2   3   9   6   8   9
g   0   1   0   3   1   5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `rowSums`

```
df[rowSums(df == 0) < 3, ]

#  i j  k l m n
#b 8 6 34 1 0 0
#d 7 9  3 7 0 5
#f 2 3  9 6 8 9
#g 0 1  0 3 1 5
```

We can also use `apply` and count row-wise number of 0's and then subset

```
df[apply(df == 0, 1, sum) < 3, ]
```